# Recent MATLAB and Octave have stronger JPEG compression and show artifacts

Tags: image, matlab, octave

I wonder why the jpeg compression in recent MATLAB and Octave versions has gone so strong that it causes noticable compression artifacts:

1. Octave 3 jpeg image with size of 41 KB with no artifacts:
   [image: Octave 3 jpeg image with size of 41 KB with no artifacts]
2. MATLAB 9 jpeg image with size of 26 KB with artifacts:
   [image: MATLAB 9 jpeg image with size of 26 KB with artifacts]
3. Octave 5 jpeg image with size of 23 KB with artifacts:
   [image: Octave 5 jpeg image with size of 23 KB with artifacts]

Here is the code to plot:

```
description = strcat('version-', num2str(version));% find out MATLAB/Octave version

x=1:2; % simple var

figure; % plot
plot(x, x);
title(description);

print(strcat("test_jpeg_size_", description ,'.jpg'), '-djpeg'); % write file
```

Do you know a possibility to tell MATLAB and Octave to **do a weaker jpeg compression**. I cannot find anything like this on https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/print.html.

I know that I could plot png files and use imagemagick to convert it to jpeg with a given quality but this would be a workaround with additional tools. Or I could png files in the first place but the real images have no compression advantages for png (like like simple one here) and I would have to change a lot of other stuff.

Comment: As a side note: `jpeg` is more suited for photos. For plots of lines or flat elements it's better to use other formats like `png`, or better yet `eps`, which is a vector format

Comment: Yes, I know as I have written in my last paragraph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go for

```
f = getframe(gcf);
imwrite(f.cdata, 'Fig1.jpg')
```

where `imwrite` takes the following options

- `Compression` (compression scheme)
- `Quality` (quality of JPEG-compressed file from 0 to 100)

See the [doc](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html) of `imwrite`.

Comment: Thanks, for my real images the compression of 90 is sufficent to avoid compression artifacts.

Answer (score 6):

This *used* to be documented*, I was surprised to not find it in the documentation pages. I tested it with the latest version of MATLAB (R2019b) and it still works:

The `-djpeg` option can take a quality value between 0 and 100, inclusive. The device option becomes `-djpeg100` or `-djpeg80`, or whatever value you want to use.

```matlab
print(strcat("test_jpeg_size_", description ,'.jpg'), '-djpeg100');
```

<sup>* Or at least I *remember* it being documented... The online documentation goes back to R13 (MATLAB 6.5), and it's not described in that version of the documentation nor in a few random versions in between that and the current version.</sup>

---

However, I strongly recommend that you use PNG for line drawings. JPEG is not intended for line drawings, and makes a mess of them (even at highest quality setting). **PNG will produce better quality with a much smaller file size.**

Here I printed a graph with `-djpeg100` and `-dpng`, then cut out a small portion of the two files and show them side by side. JPEG, even at 100 quality, makes a mess of the lines:

[image: comparing -djpeg100 and -dpng]

Note that, in spite of not having any data loss, the PNG file is about 10 times smaller than the JPEG100 file.

Comment: Ah, maybe I also read about this option years ago and wondered why I could not find it anymore. But I cannot use this undocumented option since (at least) Octave 5.1 does not support this option. And yes, I know that png is useful for this example and other cases but my images that are like photos.

Comment: It's really easy: If you can live with compression artefacts and size matters, then use jpeg. If not use PNG. It's insane to increase the jpeg quality > 85 because of compression artefacts

Comment: @Cris: I've added a feature request: https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?57029